# Per app, app-specific accessibility text to speech settings (and API)

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, system-apps, accessibility, text-to-speech

BACKGROUND:

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. On my phone I am able to have a stay on top icon area with accessibility shortcuts, as in the photo posted below. I can configure this so that one of these shortcuts is a text to speech accessibility help button.

I find this very useful, because there are times where my brain is stuck trying to pay attention to something or trying to do something, and, when this happens, I cannot read.

This is where text so speech comes in handy. As shown in the image, it can read stuff on the screen aloud for me, so that I can hear it and understand it.

................................

WHAT THIS POST IS ABOUT:

I think this feature could be improved. For instance, when I use it with an application (in this case, WhatsApp, see again image below, see the blue shaking speakerphone icon), I would like specific app-specific settings to be enabled and switched on the go as per my preferences, or needs.

For instance, in WhatsApp,

- it would be nice if I could choose not to have the times of the messages to be read aloud
- it would be nice if I could use a separate voice to read text from the other person she text to the other person
- you may not want to elect to read all of the information at the top (about who the conversation is with and what all the icons are, such as phone, video, etc. Perhaps, you are simply able to view and click on this, but it's the text which you would like to be read out to you.

Furthermore, it would also be nice if text to speech could be configured so as to, in each app, automatically scroll the app when the text reached the bottom, or wrap around.

You're after interaction speed and naturalness.

These would be per app settings.

It would be nice if a cogwheel, where the app could post a list of per-app settings, each of which could be specificalky ticked on or off as the text was getting read, could appear, on top (perhaps as a menu with a semitransparent background).

This would make this feature much more user friendly, useful, and usable.

In order for this to happen, there must be, at the software level, a protocol for the exchange of information between each app, and thus accessibility text to speech reader (via an API), that would allow both to provide support such as the one I described.

This would be really nice.

Is anyone working on this?

When will this be implemented?

How do I enable this per app text to speech support on Android?

Thanks.

[image: WhatsApp chat]